# Text expansion when writing email (Gmail, etc.)

Tags: keyboard, gmail, email, text-input

On desktop PC, there are great apps / Chrome addons such as Gorgias that allows to write `abc <TAB>` and this will be automatically expanded into a long text, thus saving many keypresses.

On Android, there is Texpand app that does mostly this, by using accessibility features of Android.

Problem: it works when writing a SMS, but **this doesn't work in text fields on web pages (for example in Chrome, while using gmail.com).** (the [Texpand FAQ item 3](http://texpandapp.com/faq.html) says it doesn't work and I can confirm).

Sadly this is exactly where such an add on would be the most useful: to write emails faster on phone.

**Question: how to have text expansion on Android in Gmail?**

Comment: For the reasons mentioned in FAQ, it is unlikely any other app can do this. It may be better to use clipboard apps that float [like this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazing_create.android.andclipfree) or other similar apps

Comment: Thanks @beeshyams. Something I don't understand: as Texpand uses accessibility features, it happens directly at the (relatively) low-level keyboard input layer, and not at the app layer? Then why is a keyboard accessibility feature dependent of the app or type of input box? Whenever an Android keyboard is displayed, the accessibility feature should be enabled, right?